# How can I flip the axes and format the values of a DataFrame using python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-lab, streamlit

How can I **Transpose and Style** a DataFrame for viewing with Streamlit and Jupyter Lab?

I am building a python tool for financial modeling and have been using a DataFrame to store my data.

It is similar to the following.

```
# Sample data
data = {
    'Month': ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'],
    'Revenue': [10000, 12000, 11000, 13000],
    'Expenses': [4000, 4500, 4200, 4800]
}

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

When outputting the df in both Jupyter Lab and Streamlit, the column names (i.e., Revenue) are column names and the data points (i.e., 10000) are rows of data. That's fine when I'm working with the data, but I need to flip those axes when I output that data. Transpose (df.T) flips the axes properly, but then I can't style the DataFrame.

Put simply, I want Revenue, Expenses, etc. to be Row names, and the revenue data points to go across horizontally from there, and I want the Revenue data points to be formatted as currency. That's how Financial Statements are typically displayed in the industry so it's important for my end users that I display them this way.

Is there a quick way to do this with Python and Streamlit? Eventually I'll build a real front-end with HTML/CSS/JS but I want a simple way to show my progress to people in the meantime while I'm building out the application.

Comment: `df.set_index('Month').T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How can I Transpose and Style a DataFrame ..* ?

By using [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) / [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html). And here is one possible configuration :

```
s = df.set_index("Month").T.style.format("$ {0:.0f}")

st.write(s.to_html(), unsafe_allow_html=True)
# or simply use st.dataframe(s) for a classical display
```

If you have different types of columns, you might need to use :

```
num_cols = df.select_dtypes("number").columns
# or you can specify a custom list of columns names

s = (
    df.set_index("Month").T.style
        .format("$ {0:.0f}", subset=pd.IndexSlice[num_cols, :])
)
```

Output (*in Streamlit*) :

[image]

Comment: Clear, concise, and helpful! Thank you. This solved my problem. The latter example for different columns is perfect for my project.